# How do I iterate through the entire Blockchain using RPC?

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

I'd like to iterate through the entire block chain using RPC.  The process I intend to do is:

1. getblockhash 1
2. getblock (input of #1 here)
3. iterate through each transaction with GetRawtransaction (input of tx field here)
4. After getting all transactions, call getblockhash 2 (or goto nextblockhash in block)

I just want to make sure I'm enumerating the chain correctly

Comment: The above seems correct. Most probably you will also want to DecodeRawTransaction after step 3. If performance is a requirement and you are already indexing all transactions (txindex=1) consider parsing your blk*.dat local files which will be way more faster than the RPC based approach. This should help: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory#blocks_subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

Your plan is correct (use `getrawtransaction <hash> 1` to get JSON instead of HEX :D) but the RPC becomes slow > 60% of the blockchain because there's between 500 and 2k transactions to go through.
Make sure `txindex=1` is in your config so it has the rawTX data.

As suggested by George parsing the raw files stored will make a very significant difference, to save you a lot of work;
this project (by bitpay) already does a that nicely:
https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api

Comment: bump for closing this ;)?

Comment: Any code examples on how bitcore/insight-api can be used for this purpose?